# Как в discord.py проверять условие через промежуток времени

Tags: python, discord.py

Мне нужно проверять условие каждые 30 секунд в discord.py. Как это сделать? Буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, через [`tasks`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/tasks/index.html)

Вот пример кога:

```
class Tasks(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: Bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.update_message.start()

    def cog_unload(self):
        self.update_message.cancel()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=45)
    async def update_message(self):
        >>> condition

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Tasks(bot))
```